# How do I find my server?

Tags: windows, azure, web-hosting

I have a private NuGet server that I've been using for several years. I need to debug an issue on the server, the trouble is can't find any record of it, I don't know where this site is hosted. I thought it would be on Azure but it's not listed there. How can I find the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by doing a dig or nslookup for the hostname and see what the IP address is. From there, plug it into something like ip-lookup.net and see who owns the IP, and that should at least point you to the provider. You’d need to then go to the provider to check for access or troubleshoot further.

Comment: Thank you. That confirmed my thought it was on Azure and I finally found the site on the Azure portal.